# How to Secure Oracle Report 12c

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, oracleforms, oraclereports, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am new in Oracle forms and reports. I am running Oracle report 12c from Forms 12c with the code below. I am able to to run the report when I disable the security on the report (rwJaznSec). But when I enable the security it prompts for system username and password. when I enter db user it does not work nor weblogic user.
Can someone kindly help me what steps I should take next. How do I create user for the reports. I would be grateful if I can get step by step process to achieve this.
Installed products are; Oracle db 12c, Forms and Reports 12.2.1.3 and weblogic 12.2.1.3
this is the code I run from the Form to generate the report:

PROCEDURE RUN_REPORT IS

```
RO_Report_ID REPORT_OBJECT;

Str_Report_Server_Job VARCHAR2(100);

Str_Job_ID VARCHAR2(100);

v_rep VARCHAR2(100); 

Str_URL VARCHAR2(100);

PL_ID PARAMLIST ;

BEGIN

PL_ID := GET_PARAMETER_LIST('TEMPDATA');

IF NOT ID_NULL(PL_ID) THEN
DESTROY_PARAMETER_LIST(PL_ID);

END IF;


PL_ID := CREATE_PARAMETER_LIST('TEMPDATA');

RO_Report_ID := FIND_REPORT_OBJECT('REPORT1');

v_rep := RUN_REPORT_OBJECT(RO_Report_ID);

ADD_PARAMETER(PL_ID, 'P_PERIOD', TEXT_PARAMETER, :ONE.PAY_PERIOD);

ADD_PARAMETER(PL_ID, 'P_COMPCODE', TEXT_PARAMETER, :GLOBAL.COMPNAME);

SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(RO_Report_ID, REPORT_FILENAME,'H:\FORMS12C\REP_01.jsp');
 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(RO_Report_ID, REPORT_COMM_MODE, SYNCHRONOUS);

SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(RO_Report_ID, REPORT_EXECUTION_MODE, BATCH);

SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(RO_Report_ID, REPORT_DESTYPE, CACHE);

SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(RO_Report_ID, REPORT_DESFORMAT, 'PDF');

SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(RO_Report_ID, REPORT_SERVER, 'MyServer1');

Str_Report_Server_Job := RUN_REPORT_OBJECT(RO_Report_ID, PL_ID);

Str_Job_ID := SUBSTR(Str_Report_Server_Job, LENGTH('MyServer1') + 2, LENGTH(Str_Report_Server_Job));

Str_URL := 'http://my-pc:9002/reports/rwservlet/getjobid' || Str_Job_ID || '?server=MyServer1';

WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT(Str_URL, '_SELF');

DESTROY_PARAMETER_LIST(PL_ID);

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you setup authentication at installation, it's hard to give you a direct answer.

The weblogic console (likely at http://my-pc:7003/em) will have security settings for the rwservlet based on application roles, such as RW_POWER_USER, RW_ADMINISTRATOR, etc.

The following Oracle Blog post will start you down the road to see if any users are configured for security. But you're going to have to dig into the Forms/Reports 12c documentation to configure if you didn't set it up previously.

https://blogs.oracle.com/functionalarchitecture/reporting-on-user-roles-in-fusion-applications